# Is there a way to call a .php file from the .html without wiping out the view of the document?

Tags: php, html, web

I am currently using . . .

```
<form action="phpcall.php" method="POST">
.
.
.
</form>
```

to initiate my php file with a few values from an html form, and submission by a button click. This call is intended to store the entered values into MySQL DB, and generate a graph to be displayed on the html page.

Is there no way to use the data sent by the html form, to generate some data and display it within the html page without navigating away from the html page? As in the php file inserts pertinent data onto the html page (in this case an image, some simple database info and other various data).

I realize this is a fairly novice question, and this would almost be behaving like Javascript, but if I need this php file to log information to MySQL, the way to do so is not apparent to me. Perhaps setting up the html page as a php document would suffice -- therein reinstantiating all of the same html structures after each call -- but this doesn't seem elegant, and I from what I understand separate php and html files are the norm.

/e
My current "solution" is to have the .php have a mirrored format, and sort the variables from there.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is an ajax form submission.

Comment: or better still a little restructuring and submit to self

Comment: @Dagon Why would that be better?

Comment: because ajax is not the answer to every question in the universe

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, similar to this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var data = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'phpcall.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                    //do something here like display a success message

                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

This would process the PHP file without reloading or navigating away form the page

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

So if I have the php file then create a graph, would I bring this into the HTML where you have specified "//do something here like display ... "

Comment: Thats correct, you can possibly use  [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery method to add the data to the html.  Although this depends on how you are creating the graph in your PHP